# Importing Redmine to local server issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

I have to move Redmine to my local server. To achieve this, I installed Redmine on my local server first and then imported the database to my local server (mysql_dump operation). Everything is working fine; the issues, attachments etc. However there is one issue. When browsing to an issue, **"Assigned To:"** is showing as **"Assignee:"**. What is causing this and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify it in the locale file: find it in `config/locales/en.yml` (and in other languages if you need)

you need to find the label `field_assigned_to`